# Issue with nume1 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Here's a copy-paste of what MATLAB is doing after I type nume1(A) into the command window:

```
nume1(A)
%Undefined function 'nume1' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Did you mean:
numel(A)

ans =

 1034289
```

Does anyone know how to stop matlab from doing this? This is preventing me from using nume1 in the editor...

Comment: Well, do you have a function `nume1` that takes in a double? Matlab is complaining because.. well.. Undefined function 'nume1' for input arguments of type 'double'?

Comment: Ha I don't quite know what you mean here...

Comment: What I am saying is, matlab is suggesting numel(A), probably because your function nume1 doesn't take a double, or it can't find such a function called nume1.. Are you running the correct script in the editor?

Comment: "_after I type nume1(A) into the command window_": and what do you type `nume1(A)` into the command window for? What's the expected result? Is it a function? What should it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume this isn't a typo and you didn't mean to invoke the `numel` function.

Make sure you're not trying to call an M-script as a function. The first line in your `nume1.m` file should read something like

```
function argout = nume1(argin)
```

You should make sure your function is either on your MATLAB search path (type `path` in the Command Window to see what MATLAB's current search path is), or in your current working directory (type `pwd`).
To see which function or script MATLAB will use, if any, type:

```
>> which nume1 -all
```

The top most is the one that will be invoked.